# String to LocalDate --> formatting in toString

Tags: java, string, date-format

Have a text file, I used a split method to cut. All is okay except that by formatting I have problems. Expected output format:

> Ime: John , Prezime: Davidson , Datum rodjenja: 05.maj.1988, Mesto
>   rodjenja: Belgrade

Date must be "05.may.1988". Instead I get it as `05051988` as in the input file.
Where is my mistake? And what is the solution?

```
Persons person = new Persons();

String text = "John.Davidson/05051988/Belgrade Michael.Barton/01011968/Krakov Ivan.Perkinson/23051986/Moscow";

String[] valami = text.split("[ ./]+");

for(int i=0; i < valami.length; i+=4) {

    person.name = valami[i];
    person.lastName = valami[i+1];
    person.dateBirth = valami[i+2];
    person.Birthplace = valami[i+3];

    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMyyyy");
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse(dateBirth, dtf) ;

    System.out.println(person);
}
```

Persons class:

```
@Override
public String toString () {

    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MMM.yyyy.");

    String s = dateBirth.format(dtf);

    return "Ime: " + this.name + " , "
        + "Prezime: " + this.lastName + " , "
        + "Datum rodjenja: " + this.dateBirth + " , "
        + "Mesto rodjenja: " + this.Birthplace;
}
```

Comment: What result/error are you getting?

Comment: @Forex: if the answer below checks out, please mark as accepted

Comment: Describe you problems with formatting in details. What kind of error you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell from your snippets, your date of birth comes out in the same format as in the input, for example `05051988`, because of the following issues:

- You are parsing the birth date into a `LocalDate`, but never saving the `LocalDate` into the person object, so it is never used.
- In `toString()` you are trying to format the date into a string `s`, but since `dateBirth` is a string, not a `LocalDate`, it does not work. And also you are not using `s` for anything.

To solve the issues I suggest:

In `Persons` declare `dateBirth` a `LocalDate`:

```
private LocalDate dateBirth;
```

`LocalDate` is better for your model. Strings are fine for reading data and for presenting them to the user. You may add a convenience setter so that you can store your string from the split input:

```
private static DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMyyyy");

private void setDateBirth(String dateBirthString) {
    this.dateBirth = LocalDate.parse(dateBirthString, dtf);
}
```

Call like this:

```
        person.setDateBirth(valami[i+2]);
```

Now in `toString` you may format the date back into a string:

```
    return "Ime: " + this.name + " , "
        + "Prezime: " + this.lastName + " , "
        + "Datum rodjenja: " + this.dateBirth.format(dtf) + " , "
        + "Mesto rodjenja: " + this.birthplace;
```

You may also want to tell the formatter which locale to use, for example:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dtf
                = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MMM.yyyy.", Locale.forLanguageTag("bs"));
```

With the above changes your snippet prints:

```
Ime: John , Prezime: Davidson , Datum rodjenja: 05.maj.1988. , Mesto rodjenja: Belgrade
Ime: Michael , Prezime: Barton , Datum rodjenja: 01.jan.1968. , Mesto rodjenja: Krakov
Ime: Ivan , Prezime: Perkinson , Datum rodjenja: 23.maj.1986. , Mesto rodjenja: Moscow
```

Further suggestions:

- Name your class `Person` in singular because an object of the class represents just one person.
- Declare a constructor that accepts first name, last name, birth date and birth place so you don’t have to set them individually. Then declare the fields (instance variables) private.

Answer (score 1):

You need to format your date string to a LocalDate and then format it to the String pattern you want. See [API Docks for parsing and formatting here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/format.html)

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter BIRTDATE_FORMAT = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MMMM.yyyy");
private static DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMyyyy");

person.dateBirth = LocalDate.parse(valami[i+2], dtf).format(BIRTDATE_FORMAT);
```

Will print:

```
Ime: John , Prezime: Davidson , Datum rodjenja: 05.May.1988 , Mesto rodjenja: Belgrade
```

Comment: For my taste a bit to much code and too little explanation. A hint to the correct formatting and how to use it should be enough. Maybe with a [URL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for further information.

Comment: @ChW updated the answer now. More to the point as you suggested? Btw why do working answers get downvotes?

Comment: @thomas77 There are many possible reasons for downvotes, and often you will never know the thoughts behind a downvote. See [this answer on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121351).

Comment: @OleV.V. thank you for the link. I had not read it. Somehow I took it sort of personal, while giving what I thought was a solution to his question. That said, I've always appreciated the respectful and thoughtfulness that go into answers, even if I was not the one asking the question. SO has saved me for hours upon hours of research to get "something" working. It is the place to go where generous people take their free time to help others.